# Comm port not recognized when running jar file in CMD

Tags: java, netbeans, cmd, serial-port, serial-communication

For a school project i have to make a Java program to read and write to a arduino. I used the javax.comm library to make the connection through the COM port. If i run the program in netbeans it runs fine. It reads output from the arduino and can write to it. But if i run the .jar file that is generated by netbeans in cmd then the program cant find the com port. The library is used correctly because the program gives an exception that is used in the javax.comm library. 
I am frustrated and don't know what to do

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

[The COM port settings in the Ports option of Control Panel have no effect on COM port settings used in a command prompt window.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/112841)

Try using the MODE application in the CMD prompt to interact with the COM port and configure it as needed for your java application.  See the above-referenced Microsoft knowledge base article for additional details.

For example:

```
C:> MODE /?
```

will provide usage information on the MODE command.

Also, make sure your cmd prompt is running as Administrator.

Comment: And how do i use the MODE application, i cant find it on the site you suggested.

Comment: MODE is a built-in command in the cmd prompt.  See updated answer.

Comment: Nope this is not working. I set the baud rate and everything to the correct values and it gives me the same error

Comment: Can you clarify your Question by adding the Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example as explained at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and full stack trace from the exception?